# Linear Algebra topics for GRE Math Subject Test

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the Princeton Review book for reviewing for the math subject test, and have covered the topics it contains for linear algebra, such as Gaussian elimination, matrix inverses,  vector spaces, determinants, linear transformations, Cramer's rule, and eigenspaces.

Are there any other topics that should be studied before the exam? Such as singular value decomposition, spectral theorem, orthonormal bases, generalized eigendecomposition, nilpotent operators, or any other topics I have not named?

Comment: The equation
$$
\dim(U) + \dim(V) = \dim(U+V) + \dim(U \cap V)
$$
comes up once in a while; it's a linear algebra analog for inclusion exclusion

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if any of the other topics I mentioned are on the exam, particularly singular value decomposition?